# Configure Nuget Package Source using Visual Studio Code to add packages from my local Folder

Tags: visual-studio-code, blazer

Configure Nuget Package Source using Visual Studio Code to add packages from my local Folder.

1. First I added an extension for Nuget Package Manager GUI
2. In settings below is what I added.

```
{
    "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe",
    "git.terminalAuthentication": false,
    "terminal.integrated.rendererType": "canvas",
    "workbench.editorAssociations": {
        "*.ipynb": "jupyter.notebook.ipynb"
    },
,
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Visual Studio Light",
    "explorer.confirmDragAndDrop": false,
    "nugetpackagemanagergui.nuget.searchPackage.urls": [
       "C:\\packages"
    ],
    "nuget"
}
```

3. I also included a nuget.config file in my project root folder. "C:\packages"
4. Now how do I add my custom created nuget package to my project.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="MyLocalNuget" value="C:\packages" />
  </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

5. Below command fails to execute, I get this message "There are no versions available for the package 'Framework.Blazor.1.0.0'."

```
    dotnet add package Framework.Blazor.1.0.0
```

References are not added to my Project File

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly" Version="6.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.DevServer" Version="6.0.2" PrivateAssets="all" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Please suggest what I missed. Thank you